# What does 'USX' (was 'GPW') mean when switching wallets?

Tags: seed

I created a seed as I am doing a transfer to a different wallet. When I put the seed of the first password in the light wallet, on the very end, in a bubble are the three letters 'GPW' when I switch wallets and put in the new seed, the letters 'USX' show up in the bubble. What is this?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this](https://blog.iota.org/gui-wallet-release-v2-3-1-f84d1160845d) article of Dominik Schiener:

> we added a 3 character checksum for seeds. This means that you can now validate if the seed which you have are trying to login with is the correct one. All you need to do is to remember the 3 character checksum and validate upon each login.

Comment: so basically everytime you create a new seed, you get a new checksum?

Comment: Yes, if you use a different seed in the light wallet you get a different checksum. Of course same seed, same checksum.

Comment: thank you; can I ask one more question; I am investing in this but also want to be a part of it. Do you recommend I go full node to help out instead of leveraging the light wallet?

Comment: Yes, if you run a full node you help IOTA spreading.

Comment: @Ninja-Crypto Please only run a full node if the machine you are running it on is (almost) always on. Running full nodes on desktop machines that are not always on harms the network more than it helps.

Comment: Build a VM in azure but I need neighbors and the slack channel invite.